# Can an isomorphism of subgroups of a finite group always be extended to an automorphism on the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, group-isomorphism

Consider the problem:

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $H, K$ be arbitrary subgroups of $G$. Let $f: H\to K$ be an isomorphism on groups. Can we always construct $F\in\text{Aut}\,(G)$ such that $F_{|H}=f$?

I am quite sure the answer is no. To this end, I am seeking the following:

1. A concrete example of when this fails.
2. A characterization of groups where this condition fails/does not fail from a representation-theoretic perspective (if it exists).

I have searched around a bit and not come up with much else other than [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9749/characterising-extendable-automorphisms) thread on MO and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088012/expanding-an-isomorphism-between-subgroups-of-g-to-an-automorphism-on-g) thread on MSE from ten years ago, so links to (recent?) research papers are very much appreciated!

Edit: I am now aware of a paper by [Pettet](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1989-106-01/S0002-9939-1989-0968625-8/S0002-9939-1989-0968625-8.pdf) and another one by [Schupp](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1987-101-02/S0002-9939-1987-0902532-X/S0002-9939-1987-0902532-X.pdf) both of which assert that an automorphism $\phi: G\to G$ is extendable to an automorphism $\psi: E\to E$ where there is a natural inclusion $\iota: G\to E$ if and only if $\phi$ is inner. I suppose what I am seeking now is an equivalent formulation and proof of this problem (if one exists) from a representation-theoretic perspective. I would also be interested in approaches making use of homological algebra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Example 1. A normal subgroup isomorphic to a nonnormal subgroup.**
$H=\{(1),\ (1\ 2)(3\ 4),\ (1\ 3)(2\ 4),\ (1\ 4)(2\ 3)\}$ and $K=\{(1),\ (1\ 2),\ (3\ 4),\ (1\ 2)(3\ 4)\}$ are isomorphic subgroups of $S_4$, but $H$ is a normal subgroup of $S_4$ and $K$ is not. An automorphism of a group must take normal subgroups to normal subgroups.

**Example 2. An Abelian example.**
$G=\langle(1\ 2\ 3\ 4),\ (5\ 6)\rangle$ is an Abelian group of order $8$. The subgroups $H=\langle(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)^2\rangle$ and $K=\langle(5\ 6)\rangle$ are isomorphic subgroups of order $2$. No automorphism of $G$ maps $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)^2$ to $(5\ 6)$, since the odd permutation $(5\ 6)$ is not a square; also, the quotient groups $G/H$ and $G/K$ are nonisomorphic.

Answer (score 9):

The cyclic subgroups generated by $(12)$ and $(12)(34)$ in $S_4$ are isomorphic, but there is no automorphism of $S_4$ sending one to another: every automorphism of $S_4$ is inner and $(12)$ and $(12)(34)$ are not conjugate, being of different cycle types.